# Tilt ("roll") camera in three.js

Tags: three.js, 3d

I'm building a camera rig in three.js with base, stand, boom, and tilt head. Everything works fine except being able to "roll" the camera around its local Z axis. I'm not sure how the camera object's rotation, up vector, and lookAt interact.
Here's my current roll code:

```js
      // rotate camera up vector away from default ([0, 1, 0]) around camera's local Z
      this.camera.up.copy(Object3D.DefaultUp)
      tmpVector3.set(0, 0, 1)
      this.camera.up.applyAxisAngle(tmpVector3, params.cameraRoll)
      this.camera.lookAt(this.cameraLookAt)
```

what happens is that even with a constant `cameraRoll` param, the camera tilts around crazily as I animate the position in a circle around the origin. Basically I want to rotate the camera around its local Z *and* use `lookAt`, but from looking at the source it seems like [object3d.lookAt](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/core/Object3D.js) replaces the object's rotation matrix (and indeed setting `this.camera.rotation.z` has no effect). I assume the `up` vector is in the camera's local coord system, but perhaps that's not true?

Comment: Best I can come up with is to apply roll by rotating the camera on its Z axis _after_ doing `lookAt()`. It appears the the `up` vector is in world coords.